# Unable to fit a graph into a page (documentclass)

Tags: pgfplots, size, resize, documentclass

I want to fit my graph into a page in a template. I had tried several methods, not sure where to fix it.

My template need to follow the below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
```

I had tried this, it works.

```
`\documentclass[tikz,border={10pt 20pt 5pt 5pt}]{standalone}`
```

But when I added to

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=0.5}
```

Not working.

[image]

My full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book} 

% \documentclass[tikz,border={10pt 20pt 5pt 5pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=0.5}   % <---

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotstableread{
interval  carT  carD
    1    68    32
    2    94   6
    3    84   16
    4   100    0
    5   100     0
    6   83      17
    7   100     0
    8   100     0
    9   100     0
    10  89      11 
    11  100     0
    12  100     0
    13  100     0
    14  95      5
    15  95      5
    16  84      16
    17  68      32
    18  84      16
    19  95      5   
    20  89      11
        }\mydata

    \begin{axis}[
    width=\linewidth,
    height=.8\linewidth,
    ybar=0.5mm,         % <--- distance between bars (shift bar)
    bar width=2mm,    % <--- width of bars
    legend style={legend columns=-1,
      outer sep=1mm,    % <---
      font=\scriptsize, % <---
      anchor=north,
      at={(1.2,1)},
                  },
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={font=\scriptsize, inner sep=2pt}, % <---
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ylabel={Classification Accuracy (\%)},
    xlabel={Test Case},
    ymin=0, ymax=100,     % <---              
    xtick=data,
    scale only axis,     % <---
        ]
    \addplot table[x=interval,y=carT]{\mydata};
    \addplot table[x=interval,y=carD]{\mydata};
    \legend{Correct, Incorrect}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}








% \end{document}
```

Comment: It's too wide, why not just reduce the `width`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT., I did, but not worked. I need to use `\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book} `

Comment: How didn't it work? In your code you do get an error from `\pgfplotsset{compat=0.5}` because `0.5` is not a valid option, but if you change it to e.g. `compat=1.3` your code works fine, and if you change `width=\linewidth` to `width=0.7\linewidth` the plot becomes narrower. Obviously, the legend wastes a lot of space, so it might be better to place it somewhere else.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but wouldn't a stacked bar plot be useful for this kind of data since the corresponding values of "correct"  and "incorrect"  always add up to 100%:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQkkZ.png

Comment: @leandriis how do you that? can you share the MWE?

Comment: `\begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,
    width=\linewidth,
    height=.5\linewidth,
    bar width=12pt,
 legend style={cells={align=right, font=\small}},
 legend pos=south east,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={font=\scriptsize, inner sep=2pt},
    ylabel={Classification Accuracy (\%)},
    xlabel={Test Case},
    ymin=0, ymax=100,           
    xtick=data,
    ]
    \addplot+[ybar] table[x=interval,y=carT]{\mydata};
    \addplot+[ybar] table[x=interval,y=carD]{\mydata};
    \legend{Correct, Incorrect}
    \end{axis}`

Comment: @ Is there any way to maximize the space, I do not want to use `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}`?

Comment: version `0.5` is too old that will work with given code as expect. It was designed (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506158/how-to-make-the-label-to-move-into-middle-of-graph)  wit recent version `1.16`. It will eventual work with version `1.15`, but not with versions older than `1.11`. If you not specify the version, LaTeX will use installed version (which probably is the recent one, if you regularly maintained your LaTeX installation).

Comment: Please compare `axis` options in MWE in your question and and in MWE, to which your question is duplicate. You make (why?) changes in line `at={(1.2,1)},` (it push `legend˙outside of the diagram), it should be `at={(0.5,1)}` (which put `legend` below of top of diagram.